# How to alter the scaffolding output folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I can't seem to determine if the **-Folder** option was removed from the MvcScaffolding package for ASP.NET MVC.  These two links indicate that it was used for altering the output folder for the items created by the scaffolds:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/mvcscaffolding-standard-usage/

[How to change project and folder where MvcScaffolding generates controllers, views and repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318159/how-to-change-project-and-folder-where-mvcscaffolding-generates-controllers-vie)

I'm using the Package Manager Console in VS2010 for an MVC3 project.  When I try to alter the output folder when scaffolding, say, a repository, there is no -Folder option in the list of options that appear when I enter "-" and press Tab.  The options that sound closest to what I need are:

- TemplateFolders
- OverrideTemplateFolders
- PipeOutput

But I can't find good documentation on what these really do either (I tried them but couldn't actually tell what they did).  Am I missing something obvious?  Thanks!